# How can I get derivative value in R?

Tags: r, derivative

I want to get the derivative value from the function below when x = 2. Is there way to keep the form of the function and also get derivative value with out any additional package?

```
f <- function(x)
  return(x^3)
```

For example, I have tried below but they didn't work.

```
x=2
deriv(~f, "x")

x=2
deriv(~body(f),"x")

x=2
D(expression(f),"x")
```

Comment: Are you asking how to express the derivative of `x^3` (_i.e._ `3x^2`) and then evaluate that for `x = 2` ?

Comment: You could look into using the [Deriv package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Deriv/Deriv.pdf) which seems to support numerical derivatives.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `deriv`, however, one caveat is that [you can only use expressions/calls](http://www.heatonresearch.com/2013/03/01/compute-derivative-r.html).

```
derivative = deriv(~ x^3, "x") 
x <- 2
eval(derivative )
```

With a named expression:

```
f = expression(x^3)
dx2x <- D(f,"x")
```

and the rest is the same.

See this link for the documentation:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Deriv/versions/3.8.2/topics/Deriv

Comment: ... and also use `function.arg=TRUE ` socan then use the function `derivative(2)`

Answer (score 7):

This would be approximation

```
foo = function(x, delta = 1e-5, n = 3){
    x = seq(from = x - delta, to = x + delta, length.out = max(2, n))
    y = x^3
    mean(diff(y)/diff(x))
}

foo(2)
#[1] 12
```

Comment: What is the "length.out = max(2,n)" for?